# Re-using views with iCarousel ios

Tags: ios, optimization, carousel, icarousel

I am build an app with ICarousel.
There will be around 30 items in the carousel.
Each item is a view with UIImageView showing an animation.

Right now I am just creating ahead all 30 views, add them to an array, and supply to the carousel when needed.

```
        SBTViewController* iv1 = [[SBTViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SBTViewController" bundle:nil];
    SBTViewController* iv2 = [[SBTViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SBTViewController" bundle:nil];
 .....
 .....
    SBTViewController* iv30 = [[SBTViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SBTViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];


viewsarray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: iv1,iv2...  iv30]
```

and when the carousel needs more views - i just supply the views from the array

However, I start getting MemoryWarnings.
Tried to use the 'reuseView" option but it simply does not work or I misunderstand something.
Each time the following is called :

```
  - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

}
```

I just tried to change the "view" to one of my offscreen views. But it does not seem to work. the carousel shows blank screen.

What is wrong ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReusingView is designed to reduce the need to alloc/dealloc views by recycling them. But because you're storing all your views in a array it won't help you because they are all being created at once and not released anyway.

The problem is fundamentally that you are trying to load too many images into memory at once (number of views x number of animation frames per view).

You'll need to find a way to load the frames dynamically. Try my GLView library (https://github.com/nicklockwood/GLView) which includes instructions for playing animations using PVR images which can be loaded in real time. The GLView library includes a GLImageView class that works just like a UIImageView but let's you specify an array of image filenames to play instead of having to load all the images in advance.

Comment: Thanks Nick ( and thanks for the great iCarousel ! ). Could you just please help me to understand the reusingView parameter  ? Is it a pointer I get from Carousel and should load my subviews there OR is it a pointer that I need init with my view and pass it back to Carousel ?

Comment: iCarousel might contain 10,000 views, but only a few will be visible at a time, so instead of either storing 10,000 views in an array, or constantly allocating an releasing views, iCarousel jut recycles the same few views. Each time a view moves off screen it is recycled an used for the next view that scrolls on screen.

Comment: So if the reusingView parameter is nil, you should create a new view and return it. If the reusingView parameter is not nil, you can either just ignore it and return a new view anyway, or you can reset it's properties (anything that is unique to a particular carousel item index) and return it.

Comment: The demo apps included with iCarousel show the correct way to use the reusingView property. Heed the warnings about not doing index-specific stuff inside the if (view == nil) clause. If in doubt, it's better to just ignore the reusingView property as the performance benefit of using it is minor but it's easy to use it wrong.